# Does Diff care about filename?

Tags: bash, diff, filenames

I am working on testing files, comparing them and i was wondering :

Does the diff command in bash care about filename?
Here's my example :

I have a file :

```
shswitch_313083_126.138.36.253_11894
```

And another one :

```
MP-313083-Sw1-126.138.36.253
```

They contains exactly the same things.
When i am doing this :

```
if diff $LOCALDIR'/liste/'$filename $DIR'/working-dir/shswitch_'$codesite'_'$ip'_'*'_OUTPUTCONFIG' >/dev/null ; then
```

Diff returns me something different than /dev/null
So, does diff cares about filename? Or is there trouble with my code? What should I use for return whether the files contains same things without caring about filenames ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  `diff` *doesn't* and would probably, *never*, care about filenames.

Comment: I am trying to overwrite the second file if the contains match his.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simply check whether two files are same or different, you can say:

```
diff -q file1 file2 > /dev/null && echo "Files are identical" || echo "Files differ"
```

Using `-q` would report only whether the files are different or not.

In order to perform an action if the files are different, say:

```
diff -q file1 file2 > /dev/null || some_command
```

Comment: Well, this is in a program, and i have 2 cases, if it's different :
Overwrite file2 with file1
If it's not, just update a database.

So basicaly, i just need the -q option ?

Answer (score 1):

`diff`definitely doesn't care about filename. It returns 0 if the file contents are identical, else it returns 1 if there are other differences and 2 if some file does not exists. By the way, a program never returns `/dev/null`, this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Isn't it /dev/null to use in my "if" ?

Comment: In the code snippet you provided, the output of `diff` standard output is redirected (with the `>` character) to `/dev/null` since the possible differences are irrelevant to your problem. As @devnull pointed out, you'd achieve the same result using the `-q` switch (wich stands for _quiet_ output). So yes, keep using either `-q`or `> /dev/null` but don't be mistaken : this has nothing to do with the code returned by `diff`. In your case, you'd be better off with something `if diff -q file1 file2; then # ... blah different ; else # ... blah not diff ...; fi`

Comment: I used what Devnull said instead of if else. it works :) thanks guys